# C^1 function with bad behavior at boundary

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a $C^1_{\text{loc}}$ function $f : \mathbb R \times \mathbb R_{>0} \to \mathbb R$ (by this I mean I know that the partial derivatives are continuous, but they're not bounded as you approach the boundary).

I know that there exists a dense sequence of points $x_i \in \mathbb R$ so that $\lim_{y \to 0^+} f(x_i,y) =a $, and another sequence of points $x_i^\prime$ on the boundary so that $\lim_{y \to 0^+} f(x_i',y) = b$, where $a \neq b$ are two real numbers.

The question is, can I guarantee that there is any kind of pathological behavior for points at the boundary that are not among the $x_i$ or the $x_i'$?  For example, must there exist a $z$ such that

1) $\lim_{y \to 0^+} f(z,y)$ does not exist?

or

2) $\lim_{y \to 0^+} f(z,y)$ exists and is equal to some number between $a$ and $b$?

or

2) $f(z,y)$ "oscillates" between $a$ and $b$ as $y \to 0^+$, and the limit does not exist?

Basically, I am interested in any kind of bad behavior that I can guarantee must happen in this setting for some $z$, without knowing much more about the function $f$ than what I have told you.

Comment: Is the sequence $(x_i')$ also supposed to be dense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: Define

$$f(x,y) = (\sin^2(x))^{1/y}.$$

Then $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R\times (0,\infty))$ (in fact $f$ is real analytic in this domain). Let $x_n'$ be the sequence

$$\pi/2,-\pi/2, 3\pi/2, -3\pi/2, 5\pi/2, -5\pi/2,\dots$$

Then $f(x_n',y)=1$ for all $n$ and all $y>0.$ But for any $x$ not in this sequence we have $\lim_{y\to 0^+}f(x,y)=0.$